# How to switch from Stereo to mono

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, sdl, decode

I'm using SDL and FFMPEG to decode audio. my test file has combination of Stereo and mono channels. When i try to play the audio file the stereo part will play, but my application fails to play when channel changes stereo to mono.

My FFMPEG is giving channel change From Stereo to mono. But how do i tell my SDL to play the Mono part.

I'm doing this in my app

```
aCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec;                                 
wanted_spec.freq = aCodecCtx->sample_rate;    
wanted_spec.format = AUDIO_S16SYS;    
wanted_spec.channels = aCodecCtx->channels;       
wanted_spec.silence = 0;    
wanted_spec.samples = SDL_AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE;    
wanted_spec.callback = audio_callback;    
wanted_spec.userdata = aCodecCtx;     

 if(SDL_OpenAudio(&wanted_spec, &spec) < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "SDL_OpenAudio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
  return -1;
 }
```

Can you tell me, How do i update channel change from stereo to mono at runtime.

Comment: How do i update channel change from stereo to mono at run time.

Comment: Please post your audio_callback.

Comment: @MetaCipher,  Please find the callback

Comment: static OSStatus audio_callback(void *userdata,Uint8 *stream,int len)
{ 
 AVCodecContext *aCodecCtx = (AVCodecContext *)userdata;
 int len1, audio_size;

 static uint8_t audio_buf[(AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 3) / 2];
 static unsigned int audio_buf_size = 0;
 static unsigned int audio_buf_index = 0;
  
 while(len > 0) 
  {
  if(audio_buf_index >= audio_buf_size) 
   {
   /* We have already sent all our data; get more */
   audio_size = [refToSelf audio_decode_frame:aCodecCtx :audio_buf:sizeof(audio_buf)];
   
   if(audio_size < 0) 
    {

Comment: audio_buf_size = 1024; // arbitrary?
    memset(audio_buf, 0, audio_buf_size);
    } 
   else 
    {
    audio_buf_size = audio_size;
    }
   audio_buf_index = 0;
   }
   
  len1 = audio_buf_size - audio_buf_index;
  if(len1 > len)
   len1 = len;
  memcpy(stream, (uint8_t *)audio_buf + audio_buf_index, len1);
  len -= len1;
  stream += len1;
  audio_buf_index += len1;
 }
}

Comment: @user783692: Edit your question with the additional information, don't add unreadable comments.